# Java2 ME: Consuming web service

Tags: java, java-me, jsr172

I'm currently using NetBeans IDE, so I want to host a WebService and consume it via J2ME. Everything goes well (from writing the web service class, deploying the web server, getting the URL for the WSDL, creating the Java ME Web Service Client, then finally calling the methods).

Currently, my WebMethod `login()` looks like this:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "login")
public boolean login(@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password) {
    boolean result = false;
    System.out.println(username + password);

    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword);

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE Username = "
                + "'" + username + "' AND Password = '" + password + "'");
        res.next();
        int i = res.getInt(1);
        if (i == 1) {
            result = true;
        }

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

So I go over to my J2ME app, create the Java ME Web Service Client, enter the WSDL for this class, and I write this line of code to call the web service:

```
FirefighterService service = new FirefighterSerivce_Stub();
try {
    if (service.login("admin", "admin"); {
        System.out.println("success"); }
    else {
        System.out.println("failure"); }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It **SHOULD** work. I have tested my line of code in a Java console application, and it worked perfectly (connecting to the database, SELECTing, and then printing the result). The result should be "success". But when I call it via the web service, I always get "failure"...

If it helps, I referenced a lot from this tutorial. http://nandokakimoto.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/creating-a-j2me-web-service-client/

Does anyone have any clue as to where I possibly screwed up? :(

Comment: Please post the error you get on the backend including the stack trace!

Comment: It's alright... I forgot to include my driver into my web app. I suck, I know.

Comment: ;) Well done for finding it though 8=}

Comment: @matt, please copy your solution as an answer and [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), to help future readers of this post.

Comment: Probably better to delete the question altogether, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alright... I forgot to include my driver into my web app. I suck, I know.